# How to create a object in ember-cli-mirage?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli-mirage

I have a `foo` model that hasMany `bar` and `bar` belongsTo `baz`. How can I include the creation of `baz` when a `foo` is created together with it's `bar`? Whenver a `foo` is created a 10 `bar` must create and a `baz` is created for each `bar`

On my `/factories/foo.js` I have a

```
  afterCreate(foo, server) {
    server.createList('bar', 10, { foo });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to have the `bar` factory create its own `baz`:

```js
// factories/bar.js
export default Factory.extend({
  afterCreate(bar, server) {
    bar.update({
      baz: server.create('baz')
    })
  }
})
```

This way, every time `server.create('bar')` is called (no matter where), each bar would get updated with its own `baz`.

You could even use [the association helper](https://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/data-layer/factories#the-association-helper) to do this for you – it basically takes care of this special case of creating a `belongsTo` relationship whenever the base model is created:

```js
import { Factory, association } from 'ember-cli-mirage';

// factories/bar.js
export default Factory.extend({
  baz: association()
})
```

You could also do it directly from the `foo` factory:

```js
// factories/foo.js
afterCreate(foo, server) {
  server.createList('bar', 10, { foo }).forEach(bar => {
    bar.update({
      baz: server.create('baz')
    })
  });
}
```

Just note that base factories should be the minimal valid descriptions of your models + their relationships – if you put these auto-creating relationships in each base factory and then someone wants to write a test for a situation where these relationships *don't* exist, it'll be difficult for them. The [traits feature](https://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/data-layer/factories#traits) is designed specifically to alleviate this sort of thing:

```js
// factories/bar.js
Factory.extend({
  withBaz: trait({
    baz: association()
  })
})

// factories/foo.js
Factory.extend({
  afterCreate(foo, server) {
    server.createList('bar', 10, 'withBaz', { foo });
  }
})
```

Also be sure to give the [factory best practices](https://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/data-layer/factories#factory-best-practices) guide a read! :)

Comment: Hi Sam, thank you for the detailed answer, it was very helpful for me. I tried the traits feature which the last info you gave me, I can't show it to the template though.

```
  model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('foo', params.foo_id, {include: 'bars'});
  }
```

on my /template.hbs

```
  {{#each model.bars as |bar|}}
     <tr>
       <td>{{bar.baz.someAttributeName}} </td>
     </tr>
  {{/each}}
```